# Executing selenium scripts on CentOS by providing java-jar command in rc.local file

Tags: linux, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-grid, rc

I am trying to execute selenium scripts on CentOS by providing java-jar command in rc.local file but it throws error as:

- "Chrome not started, exited abnormally"

and the process started from chrome location `/usr/bin/google-chrome` is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.

Whereas it works if the same command is executed by opening the terminal manually and without specifying in `rc.local` file

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Running as root?

Comment: No with other user..

Comment: rc.local runs as root which needs special chrome switches.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what chrome switches are required to run from other than root user

Comment: No I meant running  chrome as root needs extra switrches. --no-sandbox I think, maybe another one.